# firebird bug, malformed string while compiling a procedure

Tags: character-encoding, firebird, firebird2.5

Simple example I get error malformed string. How to solve this?
I use Firebird 2.5, character set is none in the database.

```
set term ^ ;


create or alter procedure test4
as
declare s varchar(20);
begin

s='öööööáé';
END^

set term ; ^
```

I tried this in FlameRobin and with isql, Same result.

I used set names win1250. No effect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't advice you to use charset none in any database and it is also true for Firebird.

Even if it is supposed to be converted with [Flamerobin](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq342/), I advice you to recreate your database with the charset you want and "pump" you data from your old database to your new database with an encoded charset. A tool like [fbclone](http://code.google.com/p/fbclone/) can do this job.

Other interresting link about Firebird and charset [here](http://www.slideshare.net/mindthebird/character-sets-and-unicode-in-firebird)

Answer (score 0):

what happened to me;

i used ems sql manger firebird lite.

my db  infos like this
default charset : utf8
default collation:  unicode_ci_ai

my connection  charset was none ;
and i tried to insert

```
INSERT INTO CARI  (CARI_ID, CARI_ADI, CARI_KOD    )
VALUES ('8', 'FİLA UNİCODE_TEXT', 'FİŞA' );
```

then i get  Malformed string.

**in Short:**

**I reconnect to db with setting CHARTSET same with DataBases current  Charset (which was utf 8)** . yesSSS!!  i inserted that "unicode containing insert statement" with no problem.

---

*note*: there is too little  help with firebird. lets improve together.

Comment: I also searched for quite a while as my automatic update system generated db objects that produced malformed strings when fed with non ascii characters. It happened after I migrated my project from UNIDAC to Firedac. As no non ASCII characters were in the code this was the last thing I was checking. It took me more than a day to figure out as I seached everywhere else ...