# How to use non-ASCII-chars in procedure definitions in Firebird 2.5 / error "Malformed string"

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I try to create a procedure that contains non-ASCII-chars in Firebird 2.5.9 but I always get the following error:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
unsuccessful metadata update
-STORE RDB$PROCEDURES failed
-Malformed string
```

Here is, what I am trying to do:

```
isql -user admin -password masterkey

create database "chartest.fdb" default character set win1252

SET NAMES WIN1252;

SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_VAL_TO_TEXT (AVAL INTEGER )
RETURNS (RESULT VARCHAR(20) ) AS
begin
  if (aval = 0) then
    result = 'natürlich';
  else
    result = 'niemals';
  suspend;
end^
SET TERM ; ^
```

In Firebird 2.0 this is working fine. Why doesn't this work in 2.5 and what can I do to avoid the error?

Comment: There are at least two questions, that tackle the same problem. But in both cases a default character set NONE seems to play a role: [firebird-bug-malformed-string-while-compiling-a-procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416779) and [firebird-create-a-view-with-cyrillic-letters-in-where-clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797816).

Comment: in your terminal window issue `chcp` command. What is your actual codepage that `isql` is forced to work within? And yes, it would be safer to make a dictionary table for locale-dependent texts instead of hardcoding them into `PSQL`

Comment: The after having run isql and having made db connection - issue `select RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME, RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID from mon$attachments, RDB$CHARACTER_SETS where MON$CHARACTER_SET_ID = RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID` to make sure your codepage was applied. Right-panel comments on https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=1462 might provide more practical insights on character sets.

Comment: @Arioch'The I know, that a dictionary table is a better place for locale-dependent texts. But the same problem applies for comments etc.  We have a ton of existing sql statements, that worked fine with Firebird 2.0 but fail with Firebird 2.5. This was my try at providing an MVCE.

Comment: @Arioch'The `chcp 1252` before running `isql` makes no difference, but...

Comment: @Arioch'The ... your `mon$attachments` sql statements reveals, that indeed the current connection has NONE as character set! If I call `SET NAMES WIN1252;` before `create database` everything is working fine.

Comment: My original problem happens in IBObjects. There I set `IboDatabase.CharSet := 'WIN1252'` and get the same error when executing the script. I thought I can reproduce this with `isql` - but that only seems to be an issue with `isql` itself. So I have to search on... But thanks.

Comment: with FB 2.5 you can use TraceAPI (IBExpert or http://FBProfiler.sf.net) to see which data was passed to the server. Don't remember if there were hex dumps to manually check text encodings as bytes (if you suspect IBO or isql could have a bug).  `that worked fine with Firebird 2.0 but fail with Firebird 2.5` - yes, and that was a big issue when 2.5.0 was released, i wonder how this gotcha was unknown to you yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SET NAMES" command must be used before "CREATE DATABASE" or "CONNECT" commands to have effect. Also character set in it must exactly match real encoding of the script.

Comment: Yes, this is, what I experienced too. But the documentation does not seem to mention this: ["This command defines the character set to be used in subsequent database transactions."](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-set-names)

Comment: This is a mistake in documentation.

Comment: Just be aware that `SET NAMES` only configure the connection character set of subsequent connections, it doesn't configure the default character set of the database (which must be explicitly specified in the `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

Comment: ... and FB 2.5 is more strict in handling "wrong" characters, therefore it is working in FB 2.0 but not in FB 2.5